# Cannot execute testcase exported from selenium ide as java/junit4/remote control in eclipse ide

Tags: selenium, junit4

I am new to testing and i am trying to learn how to run recorded test cases in selenium ide in eclipse.

1. I recorded a testcase to search word selenium in the Google.
2. I exported it as java/junit4/remote control
3. Then i strated a new project in eclipse and add "java 4.12"and "selenium stand 
   alone server" external jar files.
4. I add the exporetd code to the project.
5. Then i started command prompt and executed selenium stand alone server.
6. Then i clicked run as junit in eclipse ide.

Firefox launched but an error is occured.

below is the code i executed:

```
package please;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class please {
    private Selenium selenium;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "https://www.google.lk/");
        selenium.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void testPlease() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=10SKWaOqJ46AuATcuKPAAg");
        selenium.type("id=lst-ib", "selenium");
        selenium.type("id=lst-ib", "selenium");
        assertEquals("selenium - Google Search", selenium.getTitle());
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        selenium.stop();
    }
}
```

This is what the result looks like
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Recording tests via Selenium IDE is rarely a good option, mainly because many code snippets has to be refactored, lack of abstraction, modularity and so on (list is quite long actually). Looking at your code, I think that the problem is in the `driver` you are trying to use.  According to this selenium mirror at [Github](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/dbb21c609e6507593960f88e37d406543fbe1a55/java/client/src/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.java). You should migrate to using WebDriver, instead of `DefaultSelenium`:

> @deprecated The RC interface will be removed in Selenium 3.0. Please migrate to using WebDriver.

So, `Selenium` Interface and `DefaultSelenium` Class both belong to Selenium 1 and are deprecated. Selenium has advanced to Selenium 3 (WebDriver).

You will want to use the following classes as these are part of Selenium 3 (WebDriver). `WebDriver` is an interface used by various Selenium 3 `drivers`.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
```

Then you have various drivers that you can use. `RemoteWebDriver` / `HtmlUnitDriver` / `FireFoxDriver` / `ChromeDriver` / `IEDriverServer` etc. You will want to `import` the driver in your Java class.

```
Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium();
```

Becomes

```
WebDriver driver = new FireFoxDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your running the test using Selenium-Server try: (replace firefox with your browser version:

```
    DesiredCapabilities capabillities= DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabillities.setCapability("platform", Platform.ANY);
    capabillities.setCapability("name", "Testing Selenium-2 Remote WebDriver");

    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver( new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabillities);
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    assertEquals("Google", this.driver.getTitle());
```